# sudo command not found

Tags: macos, terminal, sudo

Hello I'm trying to run an application on my Mac terminal that I need but the permission is denied:

```
-bash: /Users/yasharsadeghi/Desktop/BWI/The End - BoS./iteraplan/runIteraplan.sh: Permission denied
```

so I tried it with sudo, but when I'm executing the file with sudo I always receive:

```
Yashars-MBP:~ yasharsadeghi$ sudo /Users/yasharsadeghi/Desktop/BWI/The\ End\ -\ BoS./iteraplan/runIteraplan.sh
sudo: /Users/yasharsadeghi/Desktop/BWI/The End - BoS./iteraplan/runIteraplan.sh: command not found
```

What can I do,any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cant have spaces in your file path. change "The End - BoS." to "The End\ -\ BoS." You get "permission denied" because the script is not an executable. Use `chmod +x <filename>` to make it executable.

Comment: OP did escape the spaces correctly, though. For reference, verify the permissions on the file with `ls -la "/Users/yasharsadeghi/Desktop/BWI/The End - BoS./iteraplan/runIteraplan.sh"`.

Comment: Also, make sure the file starts with a proper [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) -- probably either `#!/bin/sh` (if it just uses POSIX shell syntax) or `#!/bin/bash` (if it uses any bash extensions or you aren't sure).